# Show [shared] text for non admins

Tags: content-editor

When I have a shared field, then I can see that this is a shared field as admin in content editor like: with the "[shared]" at the end.

[image]

but when I login with my contentmanager there is nothing an the end:

[image]

is there a settings, so that every user can see if the field is a shared field Value, because the contentmanager can not know every shared field. Or what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the display of the field sharing labels to users that are not Sitecore administrators patching the `ContentEditor.ShowFieldSharingLabels` setting with the value `true`:

```
<!--  CONTENT EDITOR SHOW FIELD SHARING LABELS
            Determines whether or not the Content Editor displays field sharing labels ([shared] and [unversioned]) to users 
            that are not Sitecore administrators.
            Default value: false
      -->
<setting name="ContentEditor.ShowFieldSharingLabels" value="true" />
```